# How to trim the date ? to get required form in java

Tags: java, datetime, substring

```
String Timertest=Time.substring(0,3)+",";
        out.println(Timertest);
```

Here i have Time value is September 25,2014 for this i need to trim and need a out put like this : Sep 25,2014  ,how can i do like this ,could anybody help me,thanks in advance.

Comment: [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");        
System.out.print(date.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for your purpose instead of manipulating your String:

```
String prevDate = "September 25,2014";
SimpleDateFormat firstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MMM,dd,yyyy").format(firstFormat.parse(prevDate)));
```

The above code transforms your String to:

```
Sep,25,2014
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `DateFormat` or even `SimpleDateFormat`.

Reference:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html

Example:

```
//read the JavaDoc for info about available patterns
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
System.out.print(sdf.format(new Date())); // current date/time
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMMM dd,yyyy" );
SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM,dd,yyyy" );
String reformattedDate = to.format( from.parse( "September 25,2014" ) );
```